# Chat message repeater for Windows

Tags: windows, chat

Can anyone recommend me a reliable web chat message repeater for Windows?

I found some spam bot programs but the maximum interval is too short. So I would like to have more messages being automatically rotated and posted in for example one minute interval.

Is there any program that can do this?

Edit: I found this program but have not tried it yet
https://www.remouse.com/

Comment: Can you be more clear? Are you using your own server, or connecting to somewhere else? If it's yours what's its server software? And I can't think of a relation with web chat and spam bot.

Comment: @onurcano22 I have in mind a windows program that you can have running. That automatically sends predefined messages after some time intervals. Messages should be sent to a chat inside opened browser window. So no server is involved or anything like that.

Comment: Should this work with any chat site, or is this going to be for a specific site? Does the chat use an IRC backend?